# how to back to the first of text file

Tags: c++, readfile

i have a txt file which have some lines ...and my code is :

```
string line;
ifstream myfile("c:\\main.txt");

bool passport = true;

while(passport==true){

    int pos1=0;
    cout<<setw(20)<<"PassPort_Number : ";
    cin>>add.Id ;
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while(!myfile.eof()){
            getline(myfile,line);
            pos1+=line.find(add.Id);
            cout<<pos1;
        }
    }

    if(pos1<0)
        passport=false;
    else {
        cout<<"PassPort Number tekrariye :d"<<endl;
    }
}
```

first time everything is ok but at the second time of running it doesn't enter to second while (while(!myfile.eof() ) ...
what's wrong with my code?

when it goes to the end of text file it doesn't back to the first of file at the next loop ... how can i back to the first of text file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call:

```
myfile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```

to set the file read pointer back to the beginning.